# What does the lifecycle of a transaction look like?

Tags: transactions, mining

Can someone please validate my understanding of a transaction's lifecycle?

From what I understand, it looks like this:

```
- Joe signs a transaction with his private key which broadcasts the transaction to the network 
- A local node (whoever is closest) picks it up and further broadcasts it to the rest of the nodes in the network (where it is stored in the mempool) 
- A node/miner eventually picks it up and packages it in a block with other transactions
- For each transaction, the miner checks that the sender is the owner of the funds, has enough funds, has enough gas
- Once initial validation is completed, the miner send this block into the EVM to compute the new state by simulating all transactions in the block 
- Once they have the new state, they find the PoW hash to win the right to propagate the block and new state to the blockchain 
- Once they propogate, the other miners look at the block and check that the PoW hash is correct 
- The Miners then send this block into their respective EVMs to double check that the proposed state is correct 
- Once this EVM calculation is completed, they all agree that this is the block that should be added to the blockchain.
```

Is this correct? Anything I'm missing?

Comment: This is correct